# Ef include linked table not getting updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this ef method where I am using this `Include` and select the parent table using the `Single` Id for `MeetingPollingId`. I am sending a model to be created into the database. Its working fine for new record where I send a `0` for the `MeetingPollingQuestionId` but when I send a value where there is already a record I wanted it to update the data and not create a new record. Is there something else I need to change for the update to working?

```
public ResultStatus SaveMeetingPollingQuestion(Model.MeetingPollingQuestion mpq)
        {
            using (var db = new NccnEcommerceEntities())
            {
                using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    ResultStatus result = new ResultStatus();

                    try
                    {


                        var meetingPolling = db.MeetingPollings
                            .Include(x => x.MeetingPollingQuestions)
                            .Include(x => x.MeetingPollingQuestions.Select(q => q.MeetingPollingParts))
                                .Single(x => x.MeetingPollingId == mpq.MeetingPollingId);

                        var newMeetingPollingQuestion = new EFModel.MeetingPollingQuestion
                        {
                            MeetingPollingQuestionId = mpq.MeetingPollingQuestionId,
                            MeetingPollingId = mpq.MeetingPollingId,
                            MeetingPollingQuestionTypeId = mpq.MeetingPollingQuestionTypeId,
                            SequenceOrder = mpq.SequenceOrder,
                            MeetingPollingParts = mpq.MeetingPollingParts.Select(p => new EFModel.MeetingPollingPart
                            {
                                MeetingPollingPartsTypeId = p.MeetingPollingPartsTypeId,
                                MeetingPollingPartsValues = p.MeetingPollingPartsValues.Select(v => new EFModel.MeetingPollingPartsValue
                                {
                                    QuestionValue = v.QuestionValue,
                                    MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId = v.MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId
                                }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
                        };

                        meetingPolling.MeetingPollingQuestions.Add(newMeetingPollingQuestion);

                        db.SaveChanges();
                        dbTran.Commit();

                        result.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Success);
                        result.Message = "Successfully uploaded.";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        dbTran.Rollback();
                        result.Message = "Error Save Meeting Polling Question" + e.Message;
                        result.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Error);

                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is an ["Upsert"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert) which is not supported "out of the box" by Entity Framework. Upserts are supported in other query languages like PostgreSQL, etc.

You will have to "roll your own" Upsert functionality using Entity Framework. Since you are using .`Add()` in your example, you are only Insert-ing data, but never updating it. To do this, you will need to check if the question id already exists.

You can do something similar to this...

```
// determine whether the question id exists
var mpqIdExists = db.MeetingPollings.AsNoTracking().Where(mp => mp.MeetingPollingId == mpq.MeetingPollingId && mp.MeetingPollingQuestionId == mpq.MeetingPollingQuestionId).Any();

if (mpqIdExists) 
{
     // update
   db.Entry(meetingPolling.MeetingPollingQuestions).CurrentValues.SetValues(newMeetingPollingQuestion);
}
else 
{
     // insert
     meetingPolling.MeetingPollingQuestions.Add(newMeetingPollingQuestion);
}

db.SaveChanges();
dbTran.Commit();
```

Courtesy of:
[More efficient way to perform a UPSERT with EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086903/more-efficient-way-to-perform-a-upsert-with-ef6)

Comment: I am getting this error message `This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'`

Comment: @Jefferson okay, that's because it thinks there are 2 dbContext's at that moment. I edited the "update" section, try that, because it is re-using the dbContext. I dont have your code so I can't run it, but it should be something close to that. For example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e877d934-9a1e-435f-986a-1aaadb021f89/attaching-an-entity-of-type-entities-failed-because-another-entity-of-the-same-type-already-has?forum=aspwebapi, also try .AsNoTracking() in the "mpqIdExists" call to turn off db tracking, so it wont create a 2nd db context.

Comment: With your update i get `The entity type HashSet`1 is not part of the model for the current context."}`